# Django rest framework send email verification

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django `djangorestframework-jwt` this is my `models.py` for user creation

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have a username.')

        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have an email address.')

        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user
```

I want to send email verification before it generates token .. what's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/

Comment: they don't include email verification details

Comment: I read something on digitalocean or mozilla a while back on email verification using DRF, but unfortunately I can't find the book mark.  Do some googling.

Comment: Are you asking to send the email, and then to generate the token? Or more so to not allow a token to be generated until the user has verified their email address?

Comment: the simplest way to activate email to log in

Comment: From a high level, you will want to override the `djangorestframework-jwt` login serializer to only return the token in the case where the user email is verified, otherwise it can return an error. You can add a variable to check if the verification can occurred as well. I can go in detail in an answer if this is the type of solution you are looking for.

Comment: just a simple activation that turns the is_active to true and let the user begin his session